# Creating Specific Folders

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using these two functions to create project folders on startup. In the beginning I'm creating only one folder named `ProjectName` but now there's other folders on the same level with `ProjectName` named `ProjectName_Inputs`, `ProjectName_Files`, `ProjectName_Outputs`. I want to create them with my below code.

I wonder how can I adapt this to my code. I mean, is it possible to use an array or for loop etc.? `path = [/ProjectName, ProjectName_Inputs, ProjectName_Files, ProjectName_Outputs]` I don't know if it's possible?

Or can you suggest a more logical way to create them?

```
Sub CreateFolders()

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

If Functions.FolderExists(path) Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    On Error GoTo FolderNotBuilt
    fso.CreateFolder path ' could there be any error with this, like if the path is really screwed up?
    Exit Sub
End If

FolderNotBuilt:
    MsgBox "A folder could not be created for the following path: " & path & ". Check the path name and try again."
    FolderCreate = False
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

This is the function that controls whether or not the directory created before

```
Function FolderExists(ByVal path As String) As Boolean

FolderExists = False
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

If fso.FolderExists(path) Then FolderExists = True

End Function
```

Comment: Save all folder names in a array  `Dim FolderNames() As Variant: FolderNames = Array("Name1", "Name2")` and then loop through the array creating each one by one.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks dude. This is the answer guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited** to amend a typo (`End With` missing) and change `Resume` to `Resume Next`and skip the possibly screwed up path

I’d go like follows

```
Sub CreateFolders()
    Dim path As Variant

    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'create and reference a FileSystemObject object
        For Each path In Array("path1*\", "path2", "path3")
            If Not .FolderExists(path) Then 'loop through paths in array
                On Error GoTo FolderNotBuilt
                .CreateFolder path ' could there be any error with this, like if the path is really screwed up?
            End If
        Next
    End With
Exit Sub

FolderNotBuilt:
    MsgBox "A folder could not be created for the following path: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & path & vbCrLf & "Check the path name and try again."
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If it can create directory it works fine. But if there's a problem it gives an error loop. I also added `End With` statement to code. Do you know how can i solve error break issue?

Comment: @Hakan, see edited code for amended code to account for the missing `End With` (sorry!) and the error loop. if it solves your question please consider marking this answer as accepted. thank you.